# Calculating edge cover for this Hypergraph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, combinatorial-designs

Let $D= \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ be a set of constants. For any subset of $D$ of cardinality $3$, we define another set (we call it hyper-edge) containing all $3 \choose 2$ pair-wise combinations (we call them nodes) of the constants. How can I compute the minimum number of hyper edges required to cover all such pair-wise combinations of constants in $D$ in general ?

I did the first non-trivial example:

Example: $D  = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$, In this case you have $4$ possible subsets, each giving us 3 nodes in a hyper edge, and picking any three such hyper-edges or any three such subsets gives us a complete cover. I list all possible hyper edges below:

- ${a_1a_2 , a_1a_3, a_2a_3}$
- ${a_1a_2 , a_1a_4, a_2a_4}$
- ${a_2a_3,a_3a_4,a_2a_4}$
- ${a_1a_4,a_1a_3,a_3a_4}$

You can take any three of these subsets and it has all the pairwise nodes.

Comment: I found a [related question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279822/minimum-covers-of-complete-graphs-by-4-cycles). The discussion is about covers by 4-cycles, but I think that the reasoning in the accepted answer can be adapted to the 3-cycle case. If my understanding is correct, the minimum should be $\lceil {n \choose 2} /3 \rceil$ in favorable cases.

Comment: i am sorry but I don't think it's the same. The OP of that post wants to cover all $\{a_i\}$ only, whereas, I would like to cover all pairwise combination of $\{a_i\}$. But thanks for the reference.

Comment: Hmm, no, that post is about covering the edges of the underlying complete graph. Take the OP's $K_5$ example: draw 5 points on a piece of paper, draw the cycles as he listed them, and you'll get a fully connected graph.

Comment: By the way, Peter Heinig's first comment to the question explains precisely what the question (and solution) is about.

Comment: Thanks alot, I think you are right, but the guess of  $\lceil{{n\choose 2}/3}\rceil$ seems highly unlikely given that for the provided example it would mean only 2 of the subsets would suffice to create a cover, but It seems almost impossible to me.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, which is why I won't offer an answer. But I would hazard the guess it must have to do with $n$ being odd or even, just like in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, now I think this problem can be cast as the minimum number of 3-cliques required to cover a fully connected graph.

Comment: As long as $n\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod 6$, you can achieve $\binom{n}2/3$ triangles using a Steiner triple system of order $n$. See https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10551 for the details. $\tag*{}$For other values of $n$, you can take a the smallest $m\ge n$ such that $m\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod 6$, take a Steiner triple system of order $m$, and restrict all of the triangles to a subset of size $n$. For example, if $n=10$, choose $m=13$, and then if e.g. the triangle $\{1,4,12\}$ appears, replace it with $\{1,4,x\}$ for some $x\in \{1,\dots,10\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is known in the literature as a *covering design*. You want $C(n,3,2)$, where $C(v,k,t)$ is the minimum number of $k$-element subsets which cover all $t$-element subsets of a given $v$-element set.

It is proven in the CRC Handbook of Combinatorial Designs (2nd ed.) that
$$
C(n,3,2)=\left\lceil\frac{n}3\left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil\right\rceil.
$$
It is easy to prove that at least this many triangles are necessary. There are $n-1$ edges at each vertex, and each triangle covers at most two edges of a given vertex.  Therefore, each vertex has a quota of $\left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$ triangles, for a total quota of $n\cdot \left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$, and each triangle contributes $3$ points to the total quota.

Finding these optimal covering designs is the hard part. When $n\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod 6$, you can use a Steiner triple system of order $n$, whose construction is described in [Skolem]. For the other congruence classes $\pmod 6$, the constructions are described in detail in the CRC Handbook on Combinatorial Designs (2nd ed), chapter $11$, section $5$, subsection $11.41$. They are too complicated for me to describe here.

If you just need some explicit designs for small $n$, they can be at [Dan Gordon's web page](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/), or the [La Jolla covering repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/table.html) (these give the same data).

> Charles J. Colbourn and Jeffrey H. Dinitz. 2006. Handbook of Combinatorial Designs, Second Edition (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications). Chapman & Hall/CRC.
>
> Skolem, T. (1958). Some Remarks on the Triple Systems of Steiner. MATHEMATICA SCANDINAVICA, 6, 273-280. https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10551